# Using monit with java

Tags: java, bash, monitoring, monit

I am using the tool `monit` to start/stop a process. I have a java file as follows:

```
class test {
 public void start()
 {
  //do something
 }
 public void stop()
 {
  //do something
 }
}
```

I want to call the start func when a start command is issued from monit and vice versa. I cannot seem to find a good tutorial explaining what steps I need to take for executing the start and stop method. do I need to write a bash script? and monit will call the bash script which in turn calls the java method?

Comment: So when monit starts the start() method runs and when monit stops the stop() method gets called?

Comment: I am actually using it on Mac OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point into a java program is the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    // args carry the command line arguments.
}
```

In your case, you should create an instance of test and call `start()` method on that instance.

```
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    test obj = new test();
    obj.start();
}
```

Java's `Runtime` class provides an option to add a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) that gets called when the java program is being terminated. You write a simple thread class that has access to the `test` instance created in the main method above so that when the shutdown hook thread's run method is called, you delegate it to test instance's stop method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. it helps. But how will monit call my java main method?

Comment: if monit can start a process, then it would simply call `java <your fully-qualified-class-name> <optional commandline arguments>`. E.g `java com.vikdor.apps.MainLauncher` where MainLauncher has the static main method defined which will do the stuff discussed in the response.